# Is there a way to set the default HTML5-Video volume?

Tags: html, html5-video

HTML5 videos always start at 100% volume.

How can I make them start at 50% volume?

Comment: Google chrome stable version 67 fixed this by disabling the volume controls on html5 video player, and basically forcing volume to always be at 100% full.  For details see: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/2lN8hckg9cg

Answer (score 56):

Assuming you're good with mixing JS into your HTML, you can leverage one of the [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events), such as `loadstart`:

```
<video onloadstart="this.volume=0.5" ...>
```

Comment: simplest answer! If only the W3C saw fit to give us a volume attribute to go along with our muted one.

Comment: All the answers are hacks, but this one at least puts the code close to the action. Although there is an argument for unobtrusiveness, I think this is a worthy exception to allow legacy coders to see why the volume is starting at 50%.

Comment: I don't know why, but onLoadStart doensn't seem to work for me (in React)

Comment: @Shahriar https://rp40jo.csb.app/

Comment: @dwelle The example works correctly, but my code still doesn't. I also tried `onLoadStart={(e) => console.log(e)}` but no seems like onLoadStart doesn't even fire.

Answer (score 42):

You can affect the `volume` property of the `<video>` element as follows:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].volume = 0.5;
```

If using jQuery then you can use their `prop` method to alter the volume in a jQuery collection object like so:

```
$("video").prop("volume", 0.5);
```

This will alter all DOM elements in the collection.

Comment: Small addition for those who don't know: this code needs to be put in browser's add-on "*monkey"(there are different implementations).

Answer (score 36):

```
var video = document.getElementById('player');
video.volume = 0.5;
```

P.S. Use [this](http://mediaelementjs.com/) script for compatibility.

Comment: Nice, small and functional. Thumbs Up!

Answer (score 22):

```
<div>
    <video id="sampleMovie" src="mp4/Premier delivery.mp4" width="777" height="582.75" controls autoplay ></video>
        <script>
        var video = document.currentScript.parentElement;
        video.volume = 0.1;
        </script>
    </div>
```

Works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to mess with javascript, you can do it like this:

```
<video muted="">
    <source src="yourvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Out of scope of question.

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery need to use a little trick:

```
$('#your_video_id').get(0).volume = 0;
```

Comment: Or just `$('#your_video_id')[0].volume = 0;`:)

Answer (score 1):

Setting the *default* volume, using jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $("video").each(function(){ this.volume = 0.5; });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The React way using `useCallback`

```js
import { useCallback } from "react"

const vid = useCallback((x) => x.volume = 0.5)

return (
    <video ref={vid} />
)
```