# JavaScript injection for controlling volume of video

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-injection

I have a sample html page here which displays a video, I am using javascript injection to play/pause the video. But now I want to control the volume as well. How do I create a function which decreases/increases the volume based on percentage?

html video - http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm

JavaScript

```
function pausevid() {         
  var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video');     
  video[0].pause();  
}  

pausevid();
```

Comment: In the interest of content quality, duplicate questions aren't permitted. Please research your inquiry before posting in accordance with [ask]. This is a duplicate of [Is there a way to set the default HTML5-Video volume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582385/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-default-html5-video-volume)

Comment: @esqew it is not a duplicate since I am using js injections compared to the link you posted. Also trying to use percentage instead of a floating number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you could directly using percentage to `video.volume` property.

You could use `parseFloat` to remove the `%` sign and divide by 100 to change it to decimal.

```js
let vol = "80%"

function pausevid() {
  var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
  video[0].pause();
  video[0].volume = parseFloat(vol) / 100;
  console.log(parseFloat(vol) / 100)
}

pausevid();
```

```html
<video></video>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to try this: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_volume.asp

Set your volume for example to 20%

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.volume = 0.2;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).