# How can I set WebView video volume to 0 in Android Auto?

Tags: android, kotlin, video, webview, android-automotive

I am playing a video in the WebView. In normal emulators, I can set the volume to 0 by dragging the volume indicator to the minimum.

```kotlin
audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
// It returns 0 on phone or tablet emulators
```

However, when I attempt to set the volume to 0 in the Android Automotive emulator, even if I drag the volume bar indicator to the minimum, it remains at 15 instead of 0, and the video audio continues to play.

```kotlin
audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
// It returns 15 in the automotive emulator
```

I tried to set it to 0 programmatically, but it didn't work.

```kotlin
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Android Automotive OS devices are very often ["fixed-volume" devices](https://developer.android.com/media/platform/output#fixed-volume) meaning the volume cannot be controlled programmatically using [that API (and others)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#isVolumeFixed()). The [generic Android Automotive OS images](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing/emulator#generic-images) are fixed-volume.

Since you're using a WebView, I'm not sure that any of the options described in [Working with fixed-volume devices](https://developer.android.com/media/platform/output#fixed-volume) are applicable, but perhaps you could change the stream volume of the video player web element? e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21859511/17997552